# Dynamic date based on Filters

Tags: date, tableau-desktop

I want to create a calculated field that is performs something like the following:

```
COUNT(IF MONTH([Date])=(MONTH(TODAY())-2) THEN [Date] END)
```

We log the time/date of an incident, so I'm counting those. I am using [Date] twice. I use [Date] for the date  and then count how many instances of the [Date] I had in a given month.

My goal is to calculate the % Difference between last month and the month prior for reporting purposes. This is super simple and I've already done that. The issue I have is that I want a dynamic report that will update based on filters. I want my report to show me June's numbers then get the %Dif of May. If I select May, I want to see April's number. And so on.

I tried creating a month Parameter with the following code:

```
Count(
IF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "January" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "February" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "March" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "April" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "May" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "June" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "July" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "August" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "September" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "October" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "November" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
ELSEIF [Parameters].[Selected Month] = "December" THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [Date])
END
)
```

This only accomplished depression. I don't believe Tableau has this functionality given my Googling. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can do this sort of thing easily in Tableau, but its hard to see what you need to change from your question. Post a little sample data and show what results you get versus what you want